# List key pairs used by instance using boto3

Tags: python

I have a script that lists all the instances in our AWS accounts. I want to add they key pair that was used to launch the instance.

I can see there is a command that lists key pairs:

```
key_pairs = ec2.describe_key_pairs()
```

But all this command does is list all the key pairs that are in that aws account.

How can I nail this down so that only the key pair that was used to launch the instance gets listed?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, since describe_key_pairs() returns key pair name and key fingerprint, what you actually need is ec2.describe_instances(): https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances

Look at the response section of this call. It's too long to paste here. You need some json parsing logic to grab the data out but it's not that difficult.